# Generating serialization assembly fails for protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, precompile

I'm attempting to use the `precompile.exe` tool to generate a serialization assembly that can be used in a Windows Phone 7 program. The data model I have uses inheritance - and runs just fine as a .NET 4.0 program (serialization works). However, when attempting to generate a serialization assembly, I get the error:

```
Adding Program.Serialization.MessagePeer...
A type can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy
at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.SetBaseType(MetaType baseType) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 138
at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.AddSubType(Int32 fieldNumber, Type derivedType, DataFormat dataFormat) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 125
at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour() in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 553
at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Add(Type type, Boolean applyDefaultBehaviour) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 494
at ProtoBuf.Precompile.PreCompileContext.Execute() in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\precompile\Program.cs:line 340
at ProtoBuf.Precompile.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Dev\protobuf-net\precompile\Program.cs:line 33
```

I've been able to repro the issue with a simpler data model:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Bar))]
public abstract class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Bar : Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using both r284 ad 2485 builds of protobuf from http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/.

The command line to `precompile.exe` is straightforward as well:

```
D:\Projects\Program\Precompile>precompile
   "..\SerializerGen\bin\Debug\SerializerGen.dll"
   -o:MySerialization.dll
   -t:MyProgram.Serialization.PeerMessageSerializer
```

**Is this a known problem in protobuf-net, or am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Interesting; I have a repro and will investigate. As a side-note, there's no way that model should work - there is a duplicate field 1 on `Foo` - did something get broken during copy/paste? (this won't impact the bug you are seeing, but it makes me doubt "and runs just fine as a .NET 4.0 program")

Comment: Oops, that's a cut/paste error, I'll fix the sample. Out of curiosity, what was the problem? I briefly tried debugging it, but then realized I don't understand enough of the logic without studying it more to come up with a quick (and correct) fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm; there was a little difference in how System.Reflection and IKVM.Reflection were reporting inherited attributes, i.e. the precompiler (which uses IKVM.Reflection) was seeing the **inherited** `ProtoIncludeAttribute`, plus 2 (instead of 1) `ProtoContractAttribute`s.

This is fixed in r571

Comment: Hmm, the fix may not be complete - after downloading and using r571, th precompile step succeeds, but attempting to use the resulting Serializer class results in a `MissingMethodException` in the Serialize() call.

Comment: @LBushkin one moment, I'll check it

Comment: @LBushkin cannot reproduce that; I have a phone-7 project working fine using the following: `var ser = new so11::MySerializer(); SO11895998.Foo foo = new SO11895998.Bar {Name = "abc", Value = 4}; var clone = (SO11895998.Bar) ser.DeepClone(foo); Debug.Assert(clone.Name == "abc"); Debug.Assert(clone.Value == 4);` - any chance you can provide more info on what it says is wrong?

Comment: @LBushkin (the `so11:` is just because I have more than one `MySerializer` in this project ;p)

Comment: Marc, which .NET framework are you targeting for WP7 when you run `precompile`?

Comment: @LBushkin my DTO assembly is 7.1; output from precompile is: Detected framework: Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71
Resolved C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\mscorlib.dll
Resolved C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.dll
Resolved ..\..\..\SO11895998\bin\release\protobuf-net.dll
Adding SO11895998.Bar...
Adding SO11895998.Foo...
Compiling MySerializer to SO11895998_Serializer.dll...
Wrote dll:SO11895998_Serializer.dll
All done

Comment: @LBushkin if you give me a stacktrace, or if you want to email me a sample project, or something - then I might be able to advise further

Comment: Interesting - well, I forced the framework version to the same as above, and now I get a `TypeLoadException` instead of `MissingMethodException`. I tried both DeepClone() as well as Serialize() - both fail (although the Serializer object instantiates just fine). I though the problem might be related to the fact I'm using a Portable Class Library for the code that hosts the serializable classes (so I can share them between WP7 client and .NET4 server) ... but after creating a WP7 class library that didn't solve things. I'll have to create a simpler repro to send you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15161/discussion-between-lbushkin-and-marc-gravell)